# How to create single xml file combining multiple xsd schema files

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I have **multiple xsd schemas** with me and I want to generate **single xml file** combining all the xsds.
I have tried with *visual studio* but I can create separate xml files from separate xsds.
I also tried the same thing in eclipse but the result was same.

What I need is to generate a *single xml file with multiple xsds and validate the same*.

Please suggest!

Comment: First u need to import one schema in other then generate XML file... one thing i want to know Are you using one schema elements in other schema ?

Answer (score 0):

Write a schema document that imports or includes all the other schema documents (import if it's a different namespace, include if it's the same namespace). Then use this new schema document as your "schema".